# How to remove user_friends facebook app permission?

Tags: facebook, permissions

`User_friends` is a default permission.
I have tried to remove for the application but the only thing that I realize is that I remove just for one user for me using:

```
delete user-id/permissions/user_friends.
```

I would like that my app to never ask this permission for all the users.
So please tell me how to proceed:

1. what to use at Access Token
2. what is the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In API V2.0 and higher there are no default permissions other than `basic_info`.

Although `user_friends` is **approved** by default, unless you're including it in your app's login code, `user_friends` won't be part of the permissions new users are prompted to accept